# WPF ListBox selection

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a problem with extended selection in `ListBox`. Let's say I have a `ListBox` with 10 items and I'm selecting first 5 of them using `Shift` button. The `SelectionChanged` event is fired with 5 items. After that I want to select 3 items from those 5, again with `Shift` button pressed, but `SelectionChanged` event is not fired. How can I react to the second selection of items, when I'm selecting 3 of those 5 previously selected ones?

Comment: you can start by posting the code so that we can examine what it is that you are doing wrong in the CodeBehind..

Comment: Hmmm. Currently I created a simple project with just one listbox and SelectedChanged event handler(so it is simplified case of my problem) but it works as I expect. Seems like the problem with my object model and bindings.

Comment: That's why I posted the example of Binding I suspect that this is your current issue..

Answer (score 0):

can you show the xaml code as well I would like to see what your binding looks like
it should looks something like this.. but I can't be certain unless I see your code

In Command binding you have used binding which has relative source binding...

consider making these changes in binding

1) using list box as Ancestortype

2) While binding use Path=DataContext.SelectionChangedCommand otherwise it will take list box as datacontext.

```
<catel:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectionChangedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}" DisableAssociatedObjectOnCannotExecute="False" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
```

here is an example of what the XAML would look like for ListBoxItem Template

```
<Grid>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Label Width="180">Field1</Label>
    <ListBox Height="200" 
            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding List1, Mode=OneWay}" 
            Name="listBox1" 
            SelectionMode="Single" 
            Width="300">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="290">
                    <TextBlock Width="90" Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
                        <ComboBox Width="180" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.List2, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" DisplayMemberPath="Field1">
                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                                        <catel:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectionChangedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}" DisableAssociatedObjectOnCannotExecute="False" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        </ComboBox>
                    </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```